# Missing tie in signatures of comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, formatting

There is something a bit wrong with the comment formatting; it seems to be like this now:

```
\interpretCommentMarkdown{#1} - \userLink{#2}
```

But it should be more like this:

```
\interpretCommentMarkdown{#1} -~\userLink{#2}
```

That is, there should be a "tie" between the hyphen and the link to the commenter's profile, so that we don't see things like this:

[image: Example of where there should be a tie]

Comment: Let's hope the site devs understand LaTeX :-)

Comment: (Just in case) To site devs: the "tie" (or the `~` character used in the question) is a non-breaking space. Or `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 1):

This question never received an official answer, but it seems clear from [Anna Lear's revision](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/859/3) that this is [status-bydesign](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-bydesign); that is, expected behavior.